# Unable to read .wav file in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am using speech_recognition to read a .wav file using the following code :

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
```

However, I get the following error:  `file does not start with RIFF id`

I tried the following solutions and use the below code, but I end up with new errors:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672289/failed-to-open-file-file-wav-as-a-wav-due-to-file-does-not-start-with-riff-id)
Code:

```
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
x,_ = librosa.load('sample_wav.WAV', sr=16000)
```

Error : `Error opening 'C:\\Users\\biswankar.das\\Downloads\\sample_wav.WAV': File contains data in an unknown format`

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060628/reading-wav-files-in-python)
Code:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read(file_path)
```

error : `File format b'\xff\xe3\x18\xc4' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported.`

I tried analyzing this file online, the format is MPEG, following are the details:
ANALYSIS DETAILS:

```
General
Format : MPEG Audio
File size : 246 KiB
Duration : 4 min 11 s
Overall bit rate mode : Constant
Overall bit rate : 8 000 b/s
FileExtension_Invalid : m1a mpa mpa1 mp1 m2a mpa2 mp2 mp3

Audio
Format : MPEG Audio
Format version : Version 2.5
Format profile : Layer 3
Duration : 4 min 11 s
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 8 000 b/s
Channel(s) : 1 channel
Sampling rate : 8 000 Hz
Frame rate : 13.889 FPS (576 SPF)
Compression mode : Lossy
Stream size : 246 KiB (100%)
```

I tried using ffmpeg as well using the below code, but I get an error while trying the same :

```
import pydub as pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "\\ffmpeg.exe"
pydub.AudioSegment.converter = r"\\ffmpeg.exe"
data = AudioSegment.from_wav("sample_wav.wav")
```

Error: `The system cannot find the file specified` - Altho I can read the same file location

Comment: Look at this post. It might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672289/failed-to-open-file-file-wav-as-a-wav-due-to-file-does-not-start-with-riff-id.

Comment: It looks like your file is misnamed. It appears to be an `.mp3` file and not a `.wav`. Have you tried renaming it (I'm not sure if librosa/libsoundfile/audioread pay attention to the file extension, but they might and could end up being confused). Note also that librosa support for MP3 depends on `audioread`. See [librosa docs](https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9458480/758174) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The error `file does not start with RIFF id` means that your file is not supported by `wave` so you have to use a different file altogether. It might be because the file might not be a `.wav` file. Look at this post for more details- [Failed to open file file.wav as a WAV due to: file does not start with RIFF id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672289/failed-to-open-file-file-wav-as-a-wav-due-to-file-does-not-start-with-riff-id).