# mistake from gtts and wave. why isn't it working?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Not working this code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import time

text_sp = "Пятница слушает Вас"
language= 'ru'
s = gTTS(text_sp, lang=language, slow=False)
s.save('sample.flac')

time.sleep(1)

import pyaudio  
import wave
chunk = 1024  
f = wave.open("sample.flac","rb")  
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  
                channels = f.getnchannels(),  
                rate = f.getframerate(),  
                output = True)  
data = f.readframes(chunk)  
while data:  
    stream.write(data)  
    data = f.readframes(chunk)  
stream.stop_stream()  
stream.close()  
p.terminate()
```

displays an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\GGTS\ky.py", line 14, in 
f = wave.open("sample.flac","rb")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\wave.py", line 631, in open
return Wave_read(f)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\wave.py", line 283, in **init**
self.initfp(f)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\wave.py", line 250, in initfp
raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

Comment: I did a search for "file does not start with riff id" and this came up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672289/failed-to-open-file-file-wav-as-a-wav-due-to-file-does-not-start-with-riff-id Do any of those solutions work for you?

Comment: I've already hooked up silero