# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' -python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**i was trying to make the user input file audio in wav or mp3 format to low pass filter it
i am supposed to use tkinter to create GUI so that use can use two buttons one to input file and other to call function runlow which is the filter i dont know where i went wrong**

**i don't know why i need to add details to the question though stackflow ?**

but i got this error :

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ezz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ezz\desktop\voicerecorder.py", line 173, in runlow
    filtered = running_mean(channels[0], N).astype(channels.dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

here is the main code

```
from cProfile import label
from doctest import master
from importlib.metadata import files
from pydoc import text
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter import ttk
import wave
import math
import contextlib
import warnings
 
outname =  (r"filtered.wav")
 



def fileaudio():
    global fname1
    fname1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Audio files", "*.wav;*.mp3"),
                                               ("All files", "*.*") ))
    print(fname1)
    
    return fname1


    

      

    
        





    
  


warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)


      
    # Change label contents
    



root =Tk()
root.geometry("1280x800")
root.resizable(False,False)
root.title("Audio filter")
root.configure(background="white")


    

#icon
image_icon=PhotoImage(file="filter.png")
root.iconphoto(False,image_icon)

#logo
photo=PhotoImage(file="filter.png")
myimage=Label(image=photo,background="white")
myimage.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

#name
Label(text="Audio filter",font="ariel 30 bold",background="black",fg="white").pack()

#entry box
def runlow():
    cutOffFrequency = 400.0
    



# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean

    def running_mean(x, windowSize):

        cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0)) 

        return (cumsum[windowSize:] - cumsum[:-windowSize]) / windowSize



# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226853/interpreting-wav-data/2227174#2227174

    def interpret_wav(raw_bytes, n_frames, n_channels, sample_width, interleaved = True):



        if sample_width == 1:

            dtype = np.uint8 # unsigned char

        elif sample_width == 2:

            dtype = np.int16 # signed 2-byte short

        else:

            raise ValueError("Only supports 8 and 16 bit audio formats.")



        channels = np.fromstring(raw_bytes, dtype=dtype)



        if interleaved:

        # channels are interleaved, i.e. sample N of channel M follows sample N of channel M-1 in raw data

            channels.shape = (n_frames, n_channels)

            channels = channels.T

        else:

        # channels are not interleaved. All samples from channel M occur before all samples from channel M-1

            channels.shape = (n_channels, n_frames)
            return channels



    



    with contextlib.closing(wave.open(fname1,'rb')) as spf:

        sampleRate = spf.getframerate()

        ampWidth = spf.getsampwidth()

        nChannels = spf.getnchannels()

        nFrames = spf.getnframes()



    # Extract Raw Audio from multi-channel Wav File

        signal = spf.readframes(nFrames*nChannels)

        spf.close()

        channels = interpret_wav(signal, nFrames, nChannels, ampWidth, True)



    # get window size

    # from http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/what-is-the-cut-off-frequency-of-a-moving-average-filter

        freqRatio = (cutOffFrequency/sampleRate)

        N = int(math.sqrt(0.196196 + freqRatio**2)/freqRatio)



    # Use moviung average (only on first channel)

        filtered = running_mean(channels[0], N).astype(channels.dtype)



        wav_file = wave.open(outname, "w")

        wav_file.setparams((1, ampWidth, sampleRate, nFrames, spf.getcomptype(), spf.getcompname()))

        wav_file.writeframes(filtered.tobytes('C'))

        wav_file.close()

#button
record=Button(root,font="ariel 20",text="Input",bg="black",fg="white",border=0,command=fileaudio).pack(pady=30)
record2=Button(root,font="ariel 20",text="Filter",bg="black",fg="white",border=0,command=runlow).pack(pady=30)

#functions to integrate





# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean









root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the filename from your input() function.

```
def input():
    fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Audio files", "*.wav;*.mp3"),
                                               ("All files", "*.*") ))
    print(fname)
    return fname # <== you dropped this

fname = input()
```

Also there's another error, you **must** use askinputfilename, not askinputfile.

FWIW you should not use the name `input()` for your function since it overwrites and disables python's built-in input function.

Comment: i got another error Exception in Tkinter callback
https://ibb.co/n0bbtQC

Comment: That's the other error I mentioned. You need to use askopenfilename, not askopenfile.

Comment: please check the code again i edited it with the new error that i got

Comment: Same problem, you forgot the return in the `if interleaved` case.

Comment: thanks! i love you ! you  dont know how much i searched for a solution for this ! thankssss